# How can I expand my remote desktop image size?

Tags: display, remote-desktop

I'm primarily a PC/*nix user and just have a MacBook Pro for the occasional iOS dev work.  Rather than clutter up my desk with multiple screens, keyboards, etc, I use my Windows box as my primary and do full screen remote connections to the other machines.  Works great for the various Windows and *nix boxes I need to access.  However, the Mac only allows me to connect (via VNC) at the resolution of the built-in screen.  The built-in screen is pretty low res compared to my large desktop monitor on the machine I'm connecting from.  Currently I can either work inside a small window, or stretch it to fit (making the pixels huge).  What I'd like to do is have a remote session at the full resolution of the machine I'm connecting from.  Any good solutions for this use case?

Comment: A very good question, however ! insufficient information is provided to answer it correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mac OS doesn't have a terminal services centric design, so the loginwindow ties the remote screen resolution tightly to the actual physical screen dimensions.

Some easy solutions are to connect the Mac to a display (or a display dongle that simulates a plug and play monitor of a resolution of your choosing to the OS) so that the OS allocates a larger pixel boundary when the user logs in.

Alternatively, you could get software like [SwitchResX](http://www.madrau.com/indexSRX4.html) to force the display to a size of your choosing.

Comment: Unfortunately, I've not had the chance to try this out.  I've since switched from iOS to Android for mobile and replaced the Apple laptop with a Lenovo.

Comment: Sounds good. The three options I listed work well - just depends on which one prefers. Not having the problem in the first place also works well :)